# Move partition only using CLI tools at same disk

Tags: linux, command-line, partition, disk, file-server

Need a help trying to get a question I couldn't find anywhere, and most solutions were outdated. Is there a CLI-only solution to move partitions between the same disk?

"parted" used to have a function for that, but the feature was dropped at 2016 due unmaintainance.

For this case, assume the partition format and data is "unknown" (non standard partition or encrypted), also assume the partition is considerably big and not possible to just create a secondary partition and clone with dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sda2

For easy understanding of the problem, assume there is a /dev/sda1 at the middle of the disk using ~70% of space.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Self solution,

**sfdisk** tool has a "bad documented" way to move partitions, so let's say I need to move my **partition 1** from disk **/dev/sda** to **sector 2048**, so the commands would be:

> sfdisk /dev/sda -N 1

The previous command will tell `sfdisk` to use partition 1 from disk `/dev/sda`.

Then, just type the beginning of partition desired, using sector or byte format.

> sda1: 2048

Typing 2048 will move **partition 1** to **sector 2048**.

Hope this works for someone else! You can also use **dd** but under your own risk, this is a safer option.

Source: Debugging commands *used by KDE Partition Manager* when moving partitions, also used by myself when need it.

Comment: `cfdisk` or `sfdisk`?

Comment: sfdisk. Thanks starbeamrainbowlabs for your contribution.